# Sort numbers (and numbers+letters) with sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting, sql-order-by

I'm trying to sort a VarChar field with Sqlite.

The field can contain numbers or numbers+letters, but I need to sort in numerical order, like this:

```
1
1a
1b
5
5x
5y
10
10d
10e
10g1
11
11a
11b
100c
100f
```

Any ideas?  I've been able to do this... it is close (but not quite) what I need:

> Pad the start of the field with '00000', and then sort on the 1st five letters

Answer (score 12):

Easy

```
select col from tbl order by col*1, col
```

Comment: Nice!  But it only works for numbers at the beginning: You'll still have "10g9" and "10g10" sort in the wrong order.

Comment: @dan true, but it works for all the data above, and definitely for the format "numbers+letters" (number _then_ letter)

Comment: What about for the case where you have letters + numbers? e.g. A1, A2, A10, etc.?

Comment: Thx helped fix a sorting problem we had

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this with the built-in functions.  Use [`sqlite3_create_collation`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html) (or the equivalent wrapper in your preferred programming language) to define a string comparison function that implements [natural sort](http://sourcefrog.net/projects/natsort/).